# How to group and count based on condition?

Tags: powerbi, dax

An example data

```
id  article   price
1   grapes    2
1   oranges   1
1   bananas   0
2   bananas   0
3   grapes    2
3   oranges   1
4   bananas   0
4   peaches   0
```

I require to first group by `id` and then count the `id` where its price sum is $`1` or more. In this case, the desired result would be 2 (`id` 1 and 3). `id` 2 is only bananas which is $0 so it wont count and `id` 4 is bananas and peaches which are also $0.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, create a measure for price sum:

```
Price Sum = SUM( fruits[price] )
```

Then:

```
Id Count = SUMX( VALUES( fruits[id]), IF ( [Price Sum] > 1, 1))
```

Result:

[image]

How it works:

Using VALUES function, we create a list of unique Ids. Then SUMX iterates the list, calculates sum for each id, checks if it's > 1, and if yes, adds it to the result.

Answer (score 1):

The formula you are looking for is:

```
ID Count =
VAR idgroup =
    GROUPBY (
        Fruits,
        Fruits[id],
        "Sum Price",
            SUMX (
                CURRENTGROUP (),
                Fruits[price]
            )
    )
RETURN
    COUNTX (
        FILTER (
            idgroup,
            [Sum Price] > 1
        ),
        [Sum Price]
    )
```

see
[Groupby Aggregations](https://exceltown.com/en/tutorials/power-bi/powerbi-com-and-power-bi-desktop/dax-query-language-for-power-bi-and-power-pivot/groupby-aggregations-in-data-model-using-dax-dax-power-pivot-power-bi/)
[Refer to columns of a table variable](https://community.powerbi.com/t5/Desktop/DAX-Is-it-possible-to-refer-to-columns-of-a-table-variable/m-p/568032)